# angularjs: form validation within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do form validation with Angular. The problem is that my form's inputs are within a ng-reapeat and they have the same name. So if one required field is not filled, the others are also shown as not valid.

To workaround this, I've used an inner ng-form as shown below. But the validation is not triggered.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

```
 <form name="referenceForm" >

      <table>

 <tbody ng-repeat="ref in vm.references | filter:{type: 'ReferenceUrl'}">
                        <ng-form name="urlForm">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="urlName" type="text" ng-model="ref.reference.urlName" ng-disabled="ref.reference.isScreenDeleted" required />
                                    <span ng-show="urlForm.urlName.$error.required">*</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="shortName" type="text" ng-model="ref.reference.shortName" ng-disabled="ref.reference.isScreenDeleted" required />
                                    <span ng-show="urlForm.shortName.$error.required">*</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn grid-button grid-edit-row btn-danger" ng-if="!ref.reference.isScreenDeleted" ng-click="toggleDelete(ref.reference)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                                    <a class="btn grid-button grid-edit-row btn-info" ng-if="ref.reference.isScreenDeleted" ng-click="toggleDelete(ref.reference)"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-form>
                    </tbody>
           </table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not a good idea to put something in the table that is not inside . 
Never know how it will work out.

Place ng-form as an attribute on  tag instead.

So you should replace this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="ref in vm.references | filter:{type: 'ReferenceUrl'}">
  <ng-form name="urlForm">
```

With this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="ref in vm.references | filter:{type: 'ReferenceUrl'}" ng-form="urlForm">
```

Comment: Great, that worked ! Thanks a lot.  Indeed, the ng-form was not rendered when placed inside the tbody...

Comment: In Angular 1.3.15, I cannot get this to work. ng-form is not picking up the parent form when used this way. I've used it to success before but within a table, this doesn't work.

Comment: It works! Also, one more thing I noticed with this code , for each row  urlForm is local variable, so you do not need to append $index to get form name for each row, for validations!